# Where are the methods specified that are needed to analyse an Analytics Data API V1 Beta report?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have added GTM and GA4 to some website apps to produce tables of detailed stats on click-throughs of ads per advertiser for a date range. I now have suitable reports working successfully using Data Studio, but my attempts to do the same using the PHP implementation of Analytics Data API V1 Beta (in order to do batch runs covering many date ranges) repeatedly hit a brick wall: the methods needed to analyse the response from instantiating BetaAnalyticsDataClient and then invoking runPivotReport or batchRunReports or batchRunPivotReports (and so on) appear not be specified.
The only example that I could work from is the ‘quickstart’ one that does a basic dimension and metric retrieval, and even this employs:

```
getRows()
getDimensionValues()
getValue()
getMetricValues
```

that do not appear in the API documentation, at least that I can find.

The JSON response format for each report is of course documented: for example the output from running runPivotReport is documented as an instantiation of runPivotReportResponse.
But nowhere can I find a specification of the methods to be used to traverse the JSON tree (vide getDimensionValues() above) and extract some output data.

Guesswork has taken me part way, but purely for example, when retrieving pivot data, should a

```
getPivotDimensionHeaders()[0]
```

be followed by a

```
getDimensionValues()
```

or a

```
getPivotDimensionValues()
```

I am obviously approaching this all wrong, but what should I do, please?